# DataTables wrapping last column automatically not formatting correctly on collapse

Tags: javascript, datatables, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use Datatables with the responsive plugin. The Datatables table works correctly until I add the responsive option. The Table immediately drops the last column and when shrinking the screen the table does not collapse properly.

I removed all my local resources and loaded from CDN and problem still exists. No errors in console. I have played around with table format and just cant get to work correctly. What is weird is my code works correctly in a Jsfiddle but when loaded using Codepen I get same problem as on my local server.

```
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Datatables Bootstrao -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <!-- Datatables Responsive -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <table id="users" class="table table-striped table-sm">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Groups</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Admin</td>
                            <td>istrator</td>
                            <td>admin@admin.com</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://">admin</a><br />
                                <a href="http://">members</a><br />
                            </td>
                            <td><a href="http://">Inactive</a></td>
                            <td><a href="http://1">Edit</a> | <a href="1">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Test</td>
                            <td>User</td>
                            <td>test@admin.com</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://">admin</a><br />
                                <a href="http://">members</a><br />
                            </td>
                            <td><a href="http://">Inactive</a></td>
                            <td><a href="http://1">Edit</a> | <a href="1">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Datatables -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Responsive -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Datatables Call function -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#users').DataTable({
                  responsive: true,
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is a codepen of the result.
https://codepen.io/xxnumbxx/pen/vYBGdmO

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The table requires: style="width:100%" attribute with bootstrap 4.